# When we execute npm build i want the build to contain my file

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to add web.config file in the build folder that is created by npm.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `copy-webpack-plugin` as it copies individual files or entire directories to the build directory. You can write the build configuration in your webpack.config.js file for the same.

Here is the link to read how to use the plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin